# Alternative way of merging vertices

Tags: mesh, vertices

Is there a faster shortcut than <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> for merge?
I have seen video examples where it was shown a line dragging from point A to B resulting merge.
It may be an add-on?

Thank you for any of you who will help me!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so real answer is that in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hz1_SndKKwU&feature=youtu.be&t=238) you link he's using an addon by Pitiwazou and he gives the links in the comments:

https://gumroad.com/l/pie_menu_editor

https://gumroad.com/l/wazou_rmb_pie_menu_v2

Old answer:

Maybe he was snapping a vertex to another one, with the *Snap* option (*Vertices* mode) and the *Automatically Merge Vertices* option enabled? You can even activate the snap tool with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: thankyou for your help! uhm no snapping was disabled, hes just remeshing in this video, here is what he does https://youtu.be/Hz1_SndKKwU?t=238

Comment: he seems to say that it's part of an addon by Pitiwazou, he even gives the links in the comments

Comment: oh thankyou so much, i don't speak in english alot so i might have miss it! thankyou for your time, you speed up my workflow alot :D